# Error converting data type varchar to float (SQL to oracle linked Server)

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-server, openquery

[image]

[Sample Data to upload is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qhswgpVCczNCUafgNFpFnkbvjZNUfltE)

Same data is uploading successfully from another server. What might be the reason behind it ???

Comment: Perhaps a character column is being converted to a number, but it does not represent a valid number.  That would just be speculation, of course.

Comment: i didn't find any mistakes like that :(  Please check sample data if you could figure it out

Answer (score 1):

What are your thousand and decimal separators set to? Check them by running the following statement:

```
SQL> select * From v$nls_parameters
  2  where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         ,.
```

It says that - in my database - a comma is a decimal character, while a dot is a thousands separator. For example:

```
SQL> select 5/2 result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
       2,5
```

So, if your source data contain separators different from your settings, that might lead to an error. In Oracle, you'd fix it as

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

Session altered.

SQL> select 5/2 result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
       2.5
```

Though, message you posted isn't standard Oracle ORA-xxxxx error message so you might need to fix it on "that" side (i.e. not on the Oracle side).